# How to make an object to become hidden or visible via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey fellow developers,

I am having trouble getting a sequence of JavaScript to hide a grid with inputs on a click event. The platform I use (appery.io) enables me to utilize a javascript sequence via click events, my previous attempts at coming up with the code script have been unsuccessful.

Can anybody help me or at least point me in the right direction?

Any and all help is appreciated!

Here is what I have attempted recently...

```
var obj = grid_QuantityLocation(obj);
    if (obj.style.visibility == 'visible') {
        obj.style.visibility = 'hidden;
    }
    else {
        obj.style.visibility = 'visibile';
    }
}
```

Sorry if I butchered it, I'm really only well versed in SQL and have little to no experience with Java.

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: I just added what I previously had. Sorry, still a little new to StackOverflow

Comment: open a debug console in your browser and put a breakpoint, maybe your "obj" don't point to the right thing.

Comment: Java !== JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Without code, it is tough to tell however, jQuery is able to do this via `.hide()` and `.show()` methods. Check out the documentation here:

- `.hide()` - http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- `.show()` - http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: I just added what I previously had.